# specify a character vector for row.names in write.table () r

Tags: r, write.table

Given the write.table line below:

```
write.table(results,file = "mydata.csv",row.names = TRUE,col.names = TRUE,sep = ",", append = TRUE)
```

I have the below result: 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aw9l3.png)

However I would like to have row.names set up for a specific character vector (called "text" in my algorithm) to have the below result for a 400 rows (Note: Again, every row is already known. My concern is how to specify it so that my output file (mydata.csv) capture it. Please see below for desired outcome:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zmT3R.png)
Please let me know if I have not been clear , and I will provide more details. Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 0):

From the `row.names` argument of `help(write.table)`:

> either a logical value indicating whether the row names of `x` are to be written along with `x`, **or a character vector of row names to be written**.

So you could add your row names vector `text` in the `row.names` argument.

```
write.table(results, row.names = text, ...)
```

Also note that `row.names = TRUE` and `col.names = TRUE` are the default values in `write.table()`, so you do not need to include them. I'm also not sure why you're using `append = TRUE`. Taking those out, your call would then be

```
write.table(results, row.names = text, file = "mydata.csv", sep = ",")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment. I tried your suggestition, but I still receive the below error: Error in write.table(results, row.names = txt, file = "mydata.csv", sep = ",") : 
  invalid 'row.names' specification. Thanks